# Trouble running Instruments on iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, profiling

I'm trying to profile my application using Instruments on the device itself.  Specifically, I'm trying to do time profiling.

Unfortunately, I just can't get it to work.  Here's the situation:

1) If I run instruments with the app signed using the developer profile on the simulator, it works.

2) If I run instruments with the app signed using the distribution profile on the simulator, it works.

3) If I run instruments with the app signed using the distribution profile on the device (which is the default case for profiling since the scheme is set to use the release build) then Xcode complains about that there's no valid provisioning profile.  That seems reasonable.

4) If I run instruments with the app signed using the developer profile on the device, then Xcode transfers the app, but then states that it's "Finished running" immediately.  The app isn't run, and in most cases there's no error message.

Sometimes, just sometimes, there's a message from the Organiser stating that device does not recognise host - E800001C.

5) Running the app directly using the developer profile works fine - I can debug as expected.

Summary - I can't run an app on a device through Instruments using a debug build - it stops before it's had a chance to start.  There are no error messages - nothing at all in the debug console.

Help?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved this. It hadn't occurred to me to check the console inside the organizer.  It said:

: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

After a bit of Googling I discovered that deleting the app from the device would solve my issue.  Now I can profile.

So easy when you know how. Hope that helps someone else.

Tim

Answer (score 1):

First of all app can be executed on simulator without signing it. Now apple has provided us the developer profile to test the app on devices.

Distribution profiles are created for submitting the app to the apple store or when application has to be distributed to the employee within the enterprise.

If want to do profiling on device do it with developer one. It should work.

Comment: Hi.  I realize all that, I was just making the situation clear.  The one thing that doesn't work is profiling on the device with the developer profile.