# "The device does not recognize this host message when running app on the device"

Tags: xcode4.3, iphone-3g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble running Instruments on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152739/trouble-running-instruments-on-ipad)

When I was trying to run my app on a device from Xcode, I got a dialog box showing me this message:

[image]

Then I pressed the OK button, and the app ran correctly, but I want to know what's going on because it's the first time I ram into this issue.

Comment: I have the same, and it has also just started for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152739/trouble-running-instruments-on-ipad