# Xcode loses connection to device while debugging

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, freeze

My app has recently started exhibiting a strange behaviour. When I build and run from Xcode, the app launches until it hits the transition from the animated launch screen to the main screen of my app. At that point Xcode says "finished running yourApp on theDevice" and the app itself sometimes continues running on the device, or sometimes freezes.

Once this has happened, Xcode behaves as though my device is disconnected until I physically unplug and replug the USB cable.

Anyone run into this before and found a solution?

Potentially related, I have recently begun to see the "The device does not recognize this host" error periodically (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152739/trouble-running-instruments-on-ipad) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843368/the-device-does-not-recognize-this-host-message-when-running-app-on-the-device)), although my app does not use Entitlements.

[image: Screenshot for connection lost]

Comment: Have you tried to restart your iPhone?

Comment: Yep, didn't help. Restoring now...

Comment: do you have connection problems with iTunes as well? ie when plugging in the phone then iTunes starts? Just to make sure its not the cable. Otherwise I would update to xCode 4.4 should you work on a previous version. There are quite several bug fixes in 4.4 !

Comment: I had the same issue trying reloadData too many times using UICollectionView. It's suspected to be the memory issue.

Comment: Actually the issue could also stem from loading some thing big like images multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and from this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/923779/game-crashes-on-iphone.html) started checking my project for images,textures etc larger than 1024 x 1024 and found one png which was around 2732 x 2048. After reducing its size I am not getting this bug.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest trying with another cable plugged in another port.